# Why doesn't PHP need $ when accessing object properties?

Tags: php, class

In PHP, when defining or accessing a variable, you use the dollar sign `$` to let the interpreter know that whatever comes immediately after `$` pertains to a variable.

However, when accessing the property of an object, only the object itself begins with `$`, not the property belonging to that object. Here's an example:

```
<?php

class Recipe 
{
    public $title;
    public $ingredients = array();
    public $instructions = array();
}

$recipe1 = new Recipe();

$recipe1 -> title = "FooBar Salad"; // This line is what I'm referencing.

?>
```

In the above example, we create a class called `Recipe` with the properties `$title`, `$ingredients` and `$instructions`, and create a new instance of the class called `$recipe1`. Then we assign the value "FooBar Salad" to the property `$title`... But we don't need a dollar sign before the name of the property, only the name of the object.

What is going on under the hood here; why doesn't the interpreter need the dollar sign in front of the property name like any other variable?

Comment: If you want to know what's going on *"under the hood"*, I suggest you start here ~ https://github.com/php/php-src. If you want to question or dig in to language design decisions, StackOverflow is not the place

Comment: *Ultimately* it boils down to why PHP was designed this way, for which you'd have to travel back in time to talk to the creators during their booze-filled night. ;)

Comment: @Phil Understood, I'll dig into the source code. I didn't realize the PHP interpreter was on github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't use $ because, there is no risk to have a constant with the same name because class constants are called statically (Class::const) and that's why, when we call a static property we use $ (Class::$property)

Comment: In a word: *syntactical disambiguation*.

Comment: @deceze: Absolutly